# python how to parse html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to parse a html div in python with BeautifulSoup.

my code:

```
url = "http://german-bash.org/action/random"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for div in soup.findAll('div','zitat'):
    output = div.find('span', 'quote_zeile').string
    print(output)
```

I want to get all span's in the div "div.zitat" but it doesn't work

Comment: How does it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only fetching the *first* such a `<span>`. Use `.findAll()` again to find *all* such spans:

```
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, from_encoding=response.info().getparam('charset'))
for div in soup.findAll('div','zitat'):
    for span in div.findAll('span', 'quote_zeile'):
        print span.string
```

This produces:

```
>>> for div in soup.findAll('div','zitat'):
...     for span in div.findAll('span', 'quote_zeile'):
...         print span.string
... 
<bigg-el> war grad schuhe kaufen

<bigg-el> konnte mich nicht entscheiden...

<bigg-el> dann hab ich halt beide genommen :D

<Sputnik> links UND rechts??
<Busstard> weisste was scheisse is?

<Parteibruder> Nöa!

<Busstard> wenn man seinen eigenen vadda um halb zehn im puff trifft....>(

<Parteibruder> LOOOOOOL
<Psyman2> Saw? gib mal ne Zusammenfassung

<Alf777> Gewalt, Blut, Folter, psychische Schäden und abgetrennte Körperteile

<Psyman2> Aha, normale Hauptschule also

<Alf777> rofl
<complex> ich verhüte nicht. frauen hüten sich vor mir -.-
<MeX> Da steht im neuen Plus-Prospekt doch tatsächlich:

<MeX> Achtung: Silvesterknaller nur aus 2 Meter Entfernung entzünden!

<MeX> Wie stellen die sich das vor? Mit nem Flammenwerfer?
```

Note that I also tell `BeautifulSoup` what encoding to use, taken from the response `Content-Type` header; this is important for this page because without it BeautifulSoup guesses wrong.

Comment: how I can display only the first spans from the first div.zitat?

Comment: @Evolutio: use `.find()` to locate the *first* match, `.findAll()` to find all elements (a list). You need to be *explicit* as to what output you expected to see.

Comment: `for div in soup.find('div','zitat'):` give an error `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'findAll'
`

Comment: @Evolutio: your error doesn't match your code. The error indicates you are trying to access `.findAll` on a text object, not on a tag or the `soup` object.

Comment: `for div in soup.find('div','zitat'):
for span in div.findAll('span', 'quote_zeile'):
print(span.string)
` is my code, why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Evolutio: It works fine for me; did you assign anything else to `div` or `span` in the code anywhere?

Comment: your code works :) Thanks
But I get this error: `raise Exception("Unsupported datatype "+str(type(data)));
Exception: Unsupported datatype <type 'unicode'>`

I edit above my code where the error is located

Comment: @Evolutio: you are passing unicode values to something; encode them first if the API requires byte strings instead. `.encode('utf8')` to encode the data to UTF-8 for example.

Comment: How I can break the loop after 2 loops? I want to display only 2 results :)

Comment: Two loops of what? `<span>` or `<div>`? You can slice the `findAll()` results with `.findAll(....)[:2]:`.

Comment: I want to display 2 `<div>` with the spans inside. Like two quotes